# "Не" или "ни" в предложении?

Tags: не-или-ни

*Он добавил, что не одно строительство так и не началось.*

Answer (score 3):

Он добавил, что **ни** одно строительство так и **не** началось.

Это классический вариант усилительной частицы НИ при наличии отрицания.

Сравнить: Сегодня у нас есть традиционные партнеры, совместно с которыми построен **не** один объект ( = **не один, а много**).

Answer (score -1):

Оба варианта возможны.

Если ***"ни одно"*** - то это усилительная частица, всё вместе означает **все** - все так и не начались, среди какого-то множества нет хотя бы одного начавшегося (строительства).

А ***"не одно"*** говорит о том, что таких, не начавшихся, - несколько, более одного, но не все (точнее - совсем не обязательно, что все).

Меняя частицу, автор может изменить и смысл. Остается полагаться на то, что он сознательно выбрал правильный вариант. Но наверняка это не всегда можно сказать даже зная контекст.

Comment: >> *А "не одно" говорит о том, что таких, не начавшихся, - несколько, более одного, но не все (точнее - совсем не обязательно, что все).* Абсолютно невозможный вариант.

Comment: @Niemand, Не вижу причин для подобных заявлений.

Comment: хотя бы один подобный пример приведете?

Comment: Пример Ваших некорректных высказываний? Да сколько угодно. А бремя аргументации лежит на авторе высказывания. Так что все примеры - на самообслуживание.